# Zoom в ImageView

Tags: android, java

Необходимо реализовать зуммирование картинки в `ImageView`, который находится в галерее.
Нужно реализовать зуммирование так, чтобы после окончания зуммирования (картинка находится в исходном размере) можно было листать на следующую картинку в галереи. Найденные решения этому не удовлетворяют, а сам пока не могу понять, как такое реализовать, ведь мы перехватываем при зуммировании все action-ы в `onTouch`. Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей - подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не хватает `onTouch` - надо переходить к [Gestures](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html). То есть надо определить некий `Gesture` (жест), по которому можно определить зум или листание.

Comment: Создавать кастомный жест? Но тут тогда нужно будет его повторить, а для юзера это не очевидно.

Comment: @DroidAlex ну извините, вы же хотите и то и это и другое...

Comment: Задача такая. Посмотрите приложение от Zinio под Андроид.